# в Vue.js не могу инициировать клик

Tags: vue.js

Не получается при клике одной кнопки, навязать событие другой кнопки

**logo.vue**

```
<template>
    <b-button @click="trigger">click</b-button> // этой кнопкой хочу кликнуть
</template>
<script>
export default {
   data () {
....
  },
  methods: {
        trigger () {
            this.$refs.click_template.click()
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

**index.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="fullpage-container">
        <div class="page-home">
            <div class="button-group">
                <b-button-group vertical>
                    <b-button type="button"  v-bind:class="[{active:index ==0}]" @click="moveTo(2)"  
ref="click_template">  // эту кнопку
                        button
                    </b-button>
                </b-button-group>
            </div>
            <div class="fullpage-wp" v-fullpage="opts" ref="example">
                ...
                <div class="page">
                    <logo v-animate="{value: 'bounceInLeft'}"></logo>
                </div>
                <div class="page">
                    <pricelist v-animate="{value: 'bounceInTop'}"></pricelist>
                </div>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Logo from '~/components/Logo.vue'
import pricelist from '~/components/Pricelist.vue'

export default {
  data () {
    var that = this
    return {
      index: 0,
      opts: {
        start: 0,
        dir: 'v',
        duration: 500,
        beforeChange: function (prev, next) {
             that.index = next
        },
        afterChange: function (prev, next) {
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    moveTo (index) {
      this.$refs.fullpage.$fullpage.moveTo(index, true)
    }
  },
  components: {
    Logo,
    pricelist,
    ...
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Решен c помощью `$emit`:

```
<logo @handleAction="moveTo"></logo>
```

а в logo.vue:

```
trigger: function () {
    this.$emit('handleAction', someParam)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
    <b-button @click.native="trigger">click</b-button>
</template>
```

просто пропиши `@click.native=""` а не просто `@click=""`